# How Accurate is DateTime.AddDays?

Tags: c#, datetime, rounding

Since DateTime.AddDays() takes a `double` parameter, I'm concerned that when you add a days, there might be some rounding errors. For example let's say I have the following loop:

```
DateTime Now = DateTime.Today;
for (int i = 0; i < 365; ++i)
{
    Now = Now.AddDays(1);
    // do something
}
```

I'm concerned that Now might start drifting away from midnight. I'm always tempted to do something like this which may be a little slower, but relieves my paranoia:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 365; ++i)
{
    Now = Now.AddDays(1.01).Date;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: If you call your proposed method with `Now = 23:59`, it will result in a wrong result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As `DateTime` stores the date internaly as 64 bit integer where one tick represents 100 nanoseconds, there is no risk of an error. One day has 864,000,000,000 ticks and `Double` has a precision of at least 15 digits. So every error is vanished when rounding to ticks because `Double` has a higher resolution than one tick if `1.0` equals one day.

This would not be true for `AddYears()`, because `Double` has not enough precision to represent one tick if `1.0` equals one year. But if you look at the `DateTime` class, you see that the design respects that fact - `AddMonths()` and `AddYears()` have both integer and not floating point arguments.

To check this just execute the following code.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

// Displays 864000000000 
Console.WriteLine(now.AddDays(1.0).Ticks - now.Ticks);
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think you are correct to worry about rounding with doubles since not all real numbers are absolutely expressible with a double -- for instance, if you were to add 1/3 of a day three times, you might not end up with exactly one day's advance.  However, in this case, 1 is a number that is absolutely expressible and as you are simply multiplying it by another number that is also absolutely expressible in a double (the number of ticks in a day), you should be ok.  The second sample is probably overkill.

Example:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i )
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j )
    {
         now = now.AddDays( 1 / 7.0 );
    }
}
Console.WriteLine( DateTime.Today);
Console.WriteLine( now );
```

Results in (on 4/20/2009)

```
4/20/2009 12:00:00 AM
4/26/2009 11:59:59 PM
```

Comment: May be you should add a note to your example. The fact that 1 can be pricisely reprersented with Double might lead to the conclusion that this is true for all integers what of course is wrong.

Comment: You'd have to add a very large number of days for that to ever be a problem.  I suspect you'd overflow the date time structure first since a double has at least 15 significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

The number of days is multiplied by an integer (the scale) and then added to the number of ticks stored by the `DateTime`. When you pass in an integer you'll end up adding an integer number of ticks.

On the other hand, I don't know what .NET does about leap seconds... I suspect it uses a pretty simple model which doesn't bother with them, leaving your code okay.

Don't forget that adding time zones add an extra complication - adding a day locally may add more than or less than a day in terms of UTC, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by drifting away from midnight?

When run, the 1st code has the last date having 4/20/2010 12:00:00 AM.
I think that is what you expect. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As in your example, I added 1 day to a DateTime variable 100,000 times and still ended with a date with a midnight time value. It appears that there is no reason to be concerned.

I'm sure they are rounding to time ticks, which eliminates any issues with drifting.